# HttpUrlConnection.connect() Query

Tags: httpurlconnection

After hours of trawling the internet and trying to make sense of the documentation I seem unable to find a resolution to this problem.

I have an application which is using an ASyncTask to connect to a server I have 3 addresses to "test" the connection.

Now the problem is when I use the Myconnection.connect() the background task just hangs if there is either no known address or a dead link.

How can I test this connection when with a dead link or dead server it hangs and does not receive any response

The errors in the Logcat are

```
07-02 12:47:13.101 13850-20562/nodomain.myapplication D/URL ERRORhttp://10.0.0.2/testdb/connection.php

07-02 12:47:13.339 13850-20562/nodomain.myapplication I/URL IS OK: [ 07-02 12:47:13.339 13850:20562 I/         ]Status : 200

07-02 12:47:13.344 13850-20562/nodomain.myapplication D/URL ERRORhttp://localhost/myPage.php
```

As you can see the only URL I get a response from is www.google.com

My code is below:

```
package nodomain.myapplication;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by Shab on 02/07/2017.
 */

public class bgWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override

    protected Void doInBackground(Void...  params)
    {
        String db_Username = "root";
        String db_Password = "";
        String db_Name = "testdb";
        String url1 = "http://10.0.0.2/testdb/connection.php"; //DEAD? (NO RESPONSE)
 (Program Hang until exception is called)
        String url2 = "http://www.google.com";                  //OK RESPONSE 200
        String url3 = "http://localhost/myPage.php";            //NO RESPONSE
        try {
            getResponseCodes(url1);
            getResponseCodes(url2);
            getResponseCodes(url3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    }

    private String encodeURLString(String value) {

        String encodedString = "";
        try {

            encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encodedString;
    }

    public static int getResponseCodes(String TheURL) throws MalformedURLException,IOException
    {
        URL oUrl = new URL(TheURL);
        HttpURLConnection oHuC = (HttpURLConnection) oUrl.openConnection();
        oHuC.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int response = 0;

        try{

            oHuC.connect();
            response = oHuC.getResponseCode();

              if(response == 200)
                 {
                    Log.i("URL IS OK","");
                 }else{
                    Log.i("URL IS NOT OK","");
                 }

            Log.i("", "Status : " + response);

        }catch(IOException e){

            Log.d("URL ERROR" + oUrl, "D");

        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

Even with the IF statement testing the response for a 200 OK it only manages to interpret one response from the 3 URL due to the URL IS OK output.

Comment: can you `curl` to test the connection?

Comment: Sorry I am not too sure how I would go about achieving that.

Comment: `curl -X GET <URL>`, `curl` can mock all HTTP operations.

Comment: Im very sorry i,ve never used cUrl before so I have 0 idea as to how to use that code and because im new to Java it,s (Currently using Android Studio) Surely there is a way in Java t test for a dead link without using cUrl or is cUrl part of Java?